# useState initial value is not set

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following is a simplified version of my requirement that is just enough to recreate the issue. Component `ColorBox` receives a prop from  `ShowColorComponent` that is used to set the initial value of `ColorBox.visible` state.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const Container = ({ Component }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Component />
    </>
  );
};

export const ShowColorComponent = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsVisible(!isVisible);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
      <ColorBox isVisible={isVisible} />
    </>
  );
};

export const ColorBox = ({ isVisible }) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(isVisible);

  console.log(visible);
  console.log(isVisible);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        widht: "50px",
        height: "50px",
        backgroundColor: "red",
        display: `${visible ? "block" : "none"}`
      }}
    ></div>
  );
};
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Component, ShowColorComponent } from "./demo";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component ShowColorComponent={ShowColorComponent} />,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

I probably should use a method to set the parent's `ShowColorComponent.isVisible` instead of redefining new state new in `ColorBox`. But why the first time I click on the button, outputs of `console.log`s shows following?

```
false
true
```

Since I'm setting value of `isVisible` as the initial value, how `visible` is false?

Here is the CodeSandbox example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-state-issue-sc58k

Comment: Why would the initial value re-set after you clicked on a button?

Comment: When I run it on codesandbox, I am getting both as false..

Comment: To be honest you dont need the second useState in ColorBox as you can just use the isVisible variable from props and it will change as soon it changes in the parent component

Comment: You would need to employ a `useEffect` to detect a change in props to update `visible`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is why the `visible` and `isVisible` are different, that is because the useState runs only the first time the React component is rendered. (Until it is unmounted and mounted again).

If you want to track the change to any variable every time it changes, use the useEffect hook, as in:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setVisible(isVisible);
  }, [isVisible]);
```

In your case, you can just delete the
`const [visible, setVisible] = useState(isVisible);` line and use your parent's isVisible in your display:

```
display: `${isVisible ? "block" : "none"}`
```

or not even render the div at all with the && operator.

```
return (
    isVisible &&
    <div
      style={{
        widht: "50px",
        height: "50px",
        backgroundColor: "red"
      }}
    ></div>
  );
```

Comment: "only runs the first time" that's a bit missleading, `useState` gets called on every rerender, though it ignores the value passed to it on future renders.

Answer (score 1):

When you render `ColorBox` `isVisible` is **false** which also makes `visible` **false** as well. But when you click, it doesn't call `setVisible`. So `visible` is still **false**, but the click did call `setIsVisible` which turned `isVisible` to **true**.

Comment: Wrong, it does rerender ColorBox.

Comment: Okay I can change it. I thought it didn't rerender Colorbox. Don't have to be so toxic about it.